Unity C++ WebGL build Error _ZN2cv3MatC1Ev
I'm trying this link to use OpenCV in unity. It works in UnityEditor but doesn't work in WebGL builds. Gives me errors when I try to build..
Errors :


Library\Bee\artifacts\WebGL\build\debug_WebGL_wasm\build.js: undefined
symbol:
_ZN2cv12VideoCaptureC1ERKNSt3__212basic_stringIcNS1_11char_traitsIcEENS1_9allocatorIcEEEEi
(referenced by top-level compiled C/C++ code)
UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow:BuildPlayerAndRun ()

Is there any solutions for this?
I will be grateful to get any solutions!

How is opencv built? Are you building it? Maybe you need to built it using emscripten sdk (toolchain) and use that built lib for webgl builds?

Does it work in a standalone build?

@Jay Do you mean Universal Windows Platform? It works on windows and editor but not in UWP..
